# pg: left join on table puts nil records first

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my project table:

```
 Column   |            Type             |                       Modifiers                       | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('projects_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 name       | character varying(255)      |                                                       | extended |              | 
 repo_id    | integer                     |                                                       | plain    |              | 
 created_at | timestamp without time zone |                                                       | plain    |              | 
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone |                                                       | plain    |              | 
 user_id    | integer                     |                                                       | plain    |              | 
 data_path  | character varying(255)      |                                                       | extended |              | 
 private    | boolean                     | default false                                         | plain    |              | 
 uniqueurl  | character varying(255)      |                                                       | extended |              | 
 urlbase    | character varying(255)      |                                                       | extended |              | 
 ancestry   | character varying(255)      |                                                       | extended |              | 
 deleted_at | timestamp without time zone |                                                       | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "projects_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_projects_on_name_and_user_id" UNIQUE, btree (name, user_id)
    "index_projects_on_ancestry" btree (ancestry)
    "index_projects_on_deleted_at" btree (deleted_at)
Has OIDs: no
```

and here is my rating_cache table:

```
 Column     |            Type             |                         Modifiers                          | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
----------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id             | integer                     | not null default nextval('rating_caches_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 cacheable_id   | integer                     |                                                            | plain    |              | 
 cacheable_type | character varying(255)      |                                                            | extended |              | 
 avg            | double precision            | not null                                                   | plain    |              | 
 qty            | integer                     | not null                                                   | plain    |              | 
 dimension      | character varying(255)      |                                                            | extended |              | 
 created_at     | timestamp without time zone |                                                            | plain    |              | 
 updated_at     | timestamp without time zone |                                                            | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "rating_caches_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_rating_caches_on_cacheable_id_and_cacheable_type" btree (cacheable_id, cacheable_type)
Has OIDs: no
```

I am doing left outer join on two tables with:

```
SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" LEFT OUTER JOIN rating_caches
ON rating_caches.cacheable_id = projects.id 
WHERE "projects"."deleted_at" IS NULL  ORDER BY rating_caches.avg desc
```

this orders the projects correctly (highest avg come first) however projects with no matching record in rating_caches table come even before the highest avg. For ex:
projects:

```
id  name
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

rating_caches:

```
id cacheable_id avg
1  3            3.0
2  2            2.5
```

result of query looks like:

```
id name
1  A
3  C
2  B
```

Shouldn't the project with id = 1 come last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `NULLS LAST`:

```
ORDER BY rating_caches.avg desc NULLS LAST
```

As a note, the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-order.html) specifies:

> The `NULLS FIRST` and `NULLS LAST` options can be used to determine
>   whether nulls appear before or after non-null values in the sort
>   ordering. By default, null values sort as if larger than any non-null
>   value; that is, `NULLS FIRST` is the default for `DESC` order, and `NULLS
>   LAST` otherwise.

Comment: okay that works. But why is that even happening? shouldn't null value come last? even doc example puts null values first http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/tutorial-join.html

Comment: null values come last as default in mysql and sqlite. Why pg has to be different?

Comment: @sonalkr132 . . . Ironically, this is a case where Postgres and SQL Server have the same behavior.  Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't (yet) support the `NULLS FIRST`/`NULLS LAST` syntax.